# How do you map a value to a sub dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
{Jason:{vegetables:{broccoli, carrot}}, Bob:{vegetables:{broccoli}}}
```

How can I map the value "potato" to Bob so that it appears in vegetables? Like this:

```
{Jason:{vegetables:{broccoli, carrot}}, Bob:{vegetables:{broccoli, potato}}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted could be valid Python (if `Jason`, `Bob` etc are variables) but you likely are working with strings and lists so I'm going to assume the following structure:

```py
my_dict = {
    'Jason': {'vegetables': ['broccoli', 'carrot']},
    'Bob': {'vegetables': ['broccoli']}
}
```

In that case, the vegetables is a list to which you can append items:

```py
my_dict['Bob']['vegetables'].append('potato')
```

If you really meant the vegetables to be a set (indicated by using curly braces), you would use:

```py
my_dict['Bob']['vegetables'].add('potato')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I meant to do the second one.

Comment: If I solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer to complete the QA cycle.